# ASP.NET MVC working with time intervals

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, time

What i am going to do is:

I have a list of project managers (each element have `FromDate` and `TillDate` properties, which represent when he or she started or ended working on the selected project). I need to write a method that will add new project manager to the list and make sure that project managers working dates wont intersect e.g.:

```
Manager1 01.01.2000 - 01.01.2010

Manager2 01.01.1999 - 01.01.2005
```

As far as i understand, i have to walk through the list and check if working span of new manager is inside of someone's else?

The point is: i don't want to use `TimeSpan` variables, because they are not bounded to date. Can somebody give me an advice how to check if 2 date spans intersects (without writing all `if`'s by my self)?

Comment: You'll certainly need to write all the if's by yourself if you don't provide any code. Since they are two different managers in your example, surely it doesn't matter if they overlap?. Anyway this really is a trivial problem. You just make sure Manager1 StartDate is not between Manager2 StartDate and EndDate AND Manager1 EndDate is not between Manager2 StartDate and EndDate

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i know that it is kinda trivial, that is why i have asked, if some in-built solution exists.

Comment: I'm more a database guy not a programmer so I'm keen to see if there are any built in solutions also

Comment: what is the data type of `FromDate` and `TillDate`?

Comment: In the meantime you should probably clarify whether two different managers are allowed to overlap or not

Comment: @zaitsman Sorry, didnt mentioned it, they are `DateTime`.

Comment: and so no two managers can have the same date ranges, correct?

Comment: @zaitsman yes, only 1 manager can be active at time.